# jQuery manipulation question

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, checkbox

I have a repeater with the following content.

With jQuery, I want to manipulate the template as following: when I activate the checkbox,
the background-color of the div with class "entryDiv" should become yellow. In the opposite case, it should become blue. Somehow, I don´t get it done.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div runat="server" class="entryDiv" id="entryDiv">
                <div runat="server" id="cbDiv" class="cbDiv">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="isUsedCheckBox" CssClass="cbIsUsed" runat="server" />
                </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I think, the following script is correct, but how to proceed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cbIsUsed').change(function() {

    });

});
```

Comment: You have a fixed id within an `ItemTemplate` of a repeater - be aware that this will create illegal markup if you have more than one item

Comment: @BrokenGlass: ASP.Net runtime will generate unique id for each item it is rendering, hence it will be handled automatically.

Comment: @Cybernate - thanks, somehow I missed the `runat="server"` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a jQuery bug- solutions only work with input checkbox, not .Net CheckBox-Control. With CheckBox, I would have to use the control-id, which seems not possible in this environment (repeater, jQuery doesn´t get the id).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.cbIsUsed').change(function() {
        var $entryDiv = $(this).closest(".entryDiv");
        if(this.checked){
            $entryDiv.css({backgroundColor:"Yellow"});
        } else{
            $entryDiv.css({backgroundColor:"Blue"});
        }
    });  
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kxBXw/1/

Comment: something with my code might be wrong, but I never get yellow divs, only blue :(

Comment: @Jan: I am not what could be the problem with rest of code. I have posted a live example @ http://jsfiddle.net/kxBXw/1/ and it works fine.

Comment: No, sorry, your solution is not right. This must be a jQuery bug. Please try rebuild my code and execute it, it does not work.

Comment: checked isn't necessarily boolean, especially with internet explorer thats why I use .is(":checked") in my solution.

Comment: With Checkbox control, jQuery doesn´t work. I had to use old input control to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. It changes the background colour of the closest ancestor element with `class` "entryDiv" to yellow or blue, depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not:

```
$(".cbIsUsed").click(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).closest(".entryDiv").css("background-color", "yellow"); 
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest(".entryDiv").css("background-color", "blue"); 
    }
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/rkWDR/4/).

Comment: Did you have a look at the link I posted in my answer? It works fine there... so there's probably something else in your code causing that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cbIsUsed').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $(this).closest('.entryDiv.').css('background', '#ffff00');
        }
        else{
           $(this).closest('.entryDiv.').css('background', '#0000ff');            
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cbIsUsed').change(function() {
    $(this).parents(".entryDiv").css("background", this.checked ? "yellow" : "white");
});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".cbIsUsed").change(function() {
  $(this).parents(".entryDiv").css("background", $(this).is(":checked") ? "yellow" : "");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTNpc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cbIsUsed').change(function() {
        var el = $(this).parents(".cbDiv");
        if($(this).prop("checked")) el.css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
        else el.css("backgroundColor", "blue");
    });
});
```

This checks if the checkbox is checked with `if($(this).prop("checked"))` and then using the `parents` method gets the parent div with the class `.cbDiv` and changes it's background colour to blue or yellow depending on what the value of checked is.

If you want to do this using CSS classes, you can use `addClass` and `removeClass`:

```
el.addClass("yellow").removeClass("blue");
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I get a script error (though it seems to work somehow)

Comment: Yeah it did, I am not getting any errors? What does the error say exactly?

Comment: object or property "prop" is not supported

Comment: Hmm, `prop` was only added to jQuery as of version 1.6 - are you using a lower version than 1.6?